# Need to update an item in a recyclerview if it has been on screen for set amount of time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

Using Kotlin, I have a recyclerview with an adapter that displays an Arraylist.  What I need to do is set a Object.viewed property if it has been on screen for 2 seconds.  Meaning if you can just scrolling quickly through the list nothing happens but if you stop and on one to read it then I need to make it as viewed, so I can increment a seen counter.

Thanks for any help or pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a handler with delay of 2 seconds & make your logic of Viewed in it. So, after 2 seconds handler will execute your code like below :

```
//Code inside bindViewHolder() method :
handler = new Handler(); // make it globally
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000); // make a runnable with your logic code of viewed.
```

Now override a method called `onViewDetachedFromWindow(VH holder)` and remove your handle callback here. so if your view get's detached before 2000 seconds, code won't be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Jeel Vankhede [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52708147/2349435) would work but slightly heavy for my taste. I would suggest to create a map `ids to currentTime`, add element there inside `onViewAttachedToWindow` and inside `onViewDetachedFromWindow` check if 2 seconds has passed. (Don't forget to remove id from map inside `onViewDetachedFromWindow` regardless)

Comment: Thank you for you response, it worked great until my Boss said he wanted them marked as view while they were still on the screen.

Comment: Well yeah, in that case postDelayed is you friend you still might want to use onViewDetachedFromWindow / onViewDetachedFromWindow to manage runnables in handler. But anyway, good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try using countdowntimer in the OnResume function.

```
Object:Countdowntimer(2000,1000)........
```